# What should I look for in a polarising filter?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, polarizer

I am wanting to invest in a polarising filter for my camera (a Canon T2i/550D). What sort of things should I be looking for? What differentiates a good polariser from a bad one? Are there any brands to go for/avoid? Do you have any particular recommendations for specific filters?