# How an HD polarizing filter make the difference as compared to a normal one?

Tags: filters, polarizer

I have a Nikon d7200 with 18-140mm lens. Should I buy a HD Circular  polarizing filter or a normal circular polarizing filter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I choose a polarizer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/how-do-i-choose-a-polarizer)

Comment: Related: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20786/is-it-worth-buying-an-expensive-cpl-filter-over-an-e-bay-cheap-one

Comment: @Corey , but my question is slightly different  .

Comment: In what way is it different? Either it's a shopping recommendation question or it is already answered.

Comment: Yes there is difference as compared to the answer suggested by Corey. As here I am asking about the HD one,right???

Comment: Also Possible Dupe: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/77568/circular-polarizing-filter-slim-or-regular

Comment: @AnasuyaDowarah - Your question, as it is, doesn't really add value to future readers. As it stands, your question can be answered by reading the 3 questions that I've linked. If you are still confused after reading the 3 linked questions, then please update this question to clarify the things you still do not understand. Right now, Slim vs Reg and Expensive vs Cheap have already been answered.

Answer (score 3):

"HD" does not have any general meaning when used to describe a filter. It is a designation that Hoya uses for one of its product lines. Hoya's [current lineup](http://www.hoyafilter.com/hoya/) includes, with their description:

- HD Nano: "More than just hard glass: improved protection performance and durability"
- HD: "The High-End Series: protect your optics, protect your investment."
- Fusion Antistatic: "Perfect for environments where dust is common, these filters require less frequent cleaning and maintenance than traditional filters."
- Pro1: "This is the standard filters *[sic]* for the digital cameras. Constant use will protect your valued lenses from expensive front element damage which could be caused by dirt, knocks or scratches."

Other brands may use HD to mean something entirely different. If you see this designation on a [$6 filter](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/972390-REG/bower_fp58cc_58mm_digital_hd_circular.html), it probably means "hey, these letters sound fancy!"

In any case, once you've figured out what the manufacturer is using the label for, match up to your own needs ­— following [How do I choose a polarizer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/how-do-i-choose-a-polarizer) for advice if you need it.

Comment: Ok,  I have been answered that HD filter make the picture look more better than the normal one.  Is it so?

Comment: @AnasuyaDowarah In general _no_. From the description above, the difference in the Hoya line is primarily in the durability — they'll be stronger and more scratch resistant. I've seen claims _elsewhere_ that the HD series has better light transmission (but note that in most cases this is not a significant issue). If you're looking at a brand other than Hoya, it could mean nothing. I guarantee that the cheapest multicoated filter from a reputable brand _even if it does not say HD_ will outperform a cheap filter like that Bower one I linked, no matter how much it says "HD" or "PRO" or whatever.