# What type and size of polarizing is needed for a Canon Rebel T4i

Tags: polarizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find the right size of filters for a lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/10864/how-do-i-find-the-right-size-of-filters-for-a-lens)

I am in the process of buying a new camera. I am getting 18-55mm lens and a 55-250 lens what size of polarizing lens do I need?

Comment: This depends on the filter thread size of your lens and does not depend on the camera. If you look at the front of your lens you will see something like `ø62` or `ø##` where `##` is the size of the polarizer you need. If you post the exact lens name, you/we can look it up.

Answer (score 3):

The standard [Canon Rebel T4i Kit](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/870177-REG/Canon_EOS_Rebel_T4i_Digital.html) comes with the EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS II Lens. This lens uses a 58mm filter size.

The Canon EF-S 55-250mm f/4-5.6 IS Lens also happens to use a 58mm filter.

So you are in luck, because both lenses will utilize a 58mm polarizing filter.

You may also find value in these other question:

- [What is the difference between a linear and a circular polarizer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/1368/what-is-the-difference-between-a-linear-and-a-circular-polarizer?rq=1)
- [How do I choose a polarizer?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/how-do-i-choose-a-polarizer?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that by polarizing lens, you mean a polarizing filter for your lens.
A filter is an attachment usually screwed on the front of a lens.

Both the lenses you've mentioned have a 58mm filter thread, so you can use the same filter on both.
However, one important point to consider is that both these lenses have a front element that rotates during focus, which makes it a little frustrating to use a circular polarizing filter.